# Table's mean_partition_size shows wrong, extremely high values

Tags: scylla

I have a table in scylla, call it 'tablex', in keyspace 'keyspacey', now, I load the data from it into Spark, and I have observed a very large number of partitions, digging in the code I saw it uses `mean_partition_size`, it could be seen using the query:

```
SELECT range_start, range_end, partitions_count, mean_partition_size FROM system.size_estimates WHERE keyspace_name = 'keyspacey' AND table_name = 'tablex';
```

tablex has 586 rows every one consists of timestamp, text, text, bigint.

Running the query above, I got 256 rows, all having partition_count=1 and nean_partition_size=5960319812.

What could be the cause of the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you hit this bug: https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/3916

Fixed in Scylla 3.0 - we would recommend an upgrade. Upgrade guide is at https://docs.scylladb.com/upgrade/upgrade-opensource/upgrade-guide-from-2.3-to-3.0/

Comment: for users who want to keep in the 2.3 train, 2.3.2 fixes this as well